# How to get maximum date value from a group of date columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, datetime

This is Sample Data:

```
import pandas as pd
d = {'name': ['john', 'tom', 'phill', 'nero', 'bob', 'rob'], 'date1' :['2015-10-05', '2015-01-05', '2015-07-06', '2015-10-06', '2015-10-06', '2015-12-08'], 'date2' :['2015-10-05', '2015-01-05', '2015-07-06', '2015-08-06', '2015-09-06', '2015-12-08'], 'date3' :['2015-07-05', '2015-11-05', '2015-07-06', '2015-11-06', '2015-05-06', '2015-05-08']}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data = d)
df2['date1'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(df2['date1'])
df2['date2'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(df2['date2'])
df2['date3'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(df2['date3'])
```

This is the table

[image]

Problem 1 : I want to create a new column max_date, which will have maximum date value for each row. I thought I could create a list of those columns and then apply max on them but it didn't work. I found numpy.amax(), but couldn't make it work.

Problem 2 : I must use column names to specify those columns, can't use position index of columns like df2[ , 0:2]

> **Update** on problem 2 - When I said ' use column names' - I meant I have a list of column names, which I need to use like [date1, date2,
>   date3]. Sorry if that wasn't clear from my post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Boolean indexing via `str.startswith`:

```
date_cols = df2.columns[df2.columns.str.startswith('date')]
df2['max_date'] = df2[date_cols].max(1)

print(df2)

       date1      date2      date3   name   max_date
0 2015-10-05 2015-10-05 2015-07-05   john 2015-10-05
1 2015-01-05 2015-01-05 2015-11-05    tom 2015-11-05
2 2015-07-06 2015-07-06 2015-07-06  phill 2015-07-06
3 2015-10-06 2015-08-06 2015-11-06   nero 2015-11-06
4 2015-10-06 2015-09-06 2015-05-06    bob 2015-10-06
5 2015-12-08 2015-12-08 2015-05-08    rob 2015-12-08
```

Comment: Although I was looking for an answer where I would be able to use a list of column names, I might be able to .str method . Will be back to give feedback on that.

Comment: Of course, you can just say `date_cols = ['date1', 'date2', 'date3']` instead.

Answer (score 6):

#### `select_dtypes`

This works on all datetime columns regardless of naming convention.

```
df2.assign(max_date=df2.select_dtypes('datetime').max(1))

       date1      date2      date3   name   max_date
0 2015-10-05 2015-10-05 2015-07-05   john 2015-10-05
1 2015-01-05 2015-01-05 2015-11-05    tom 2015-11-05
2 2015-07-06 2015-07-06 2015-07-06  phill 2015-07-06
3 2015-10-06 2015-08-06 2015-11-06   nero 2015-11-06
4 2015-10-06 2015-09-06 2015-05-06    bob 2015-10-06
5 2015-12-08 2015-12-08 2015-05-08    rob 2015-12-08
```

Answer (score 5):

Using `max` with `filter` `like`

```
df2['max_date']=df2.filter(like='date',axis=1).max(1)
df2
Out[157]: 
       date1      date2      date3   name   max_date
0 2015-10-05 2015-10-05 2015-07-05   john 2015-10-05
1 2015-01-05 2015-01-05 2015-11-05    tom 2015-11-05
2 2015-07-06 2015-07-06 2015-07-06  phill 2015-07-06
3 2015-10-06 2015-08-06 2015-11-06   nero 2015-11-06
4 2015-10-06 2015-09-06 2015-05-06    bob 2015-10-06
5 2015-12-08 2015-12-08 2015-05-08    rob 2015-12-08
```

Comment: you don't need `axis=1`